# Integral expression for covariance matrix in diffusion process

Tags: statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes

Consider the Fokker-Planck equation
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = \sum_{i,j=1}^2 \mathbf{\Gamma}_{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(x_j \rho) + \mathbf{D}_{ij}\frac{\partial^2 \rho}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$$
where
$$\rho = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ v \end{pmatrix} \quad \mathbf{\Gamma} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & \gamma\end{bmatrix} \quad \mathbf{D} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & D \gamma^2 \end{bmatrix} \, .$$
These equations represent diffusion where $\gamma$ is the coefficient of friction and $D=k_b T / \gamma m$ is the diffusion constant.

I'm reading *Elements of Nonequilibrium Statistical Mechanics* by Balakrishnan wherein this equation is studied.
The book points out that this Fokker-Planck equation is equivalent to the following Lengevin equation
$$\dot{\mathbf{x}} + \mathbf{\Gamma} \mathbf{x} = \frac{1}{m} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \eta(t) \end{pmatrix}$$
where
$$\mathbf{x} = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ v \end{pmatrix}$$
and where $\eta(t)$ is white noise satisfying $\langle \eta(t) \eta(t') \rangle = 2 m \gamma k_b T \delta(t-t').$
So far this is all fine.

The author writes

> The Langevin equation is solved with the help of the matrix Green function
> $$\mathbf{G}(t) = \exp(-\mathbf{\Gamma} t) \equiv \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-\mathbf{\Gamma}t)^n}{n!} \, .$$

This is annoying because the noise $\eta$ is left out.
However, the author then writes

> We are concerned with sharp initial conditions $\mathbf{x}_0 = (x_0, v_0)$. The average value of $\mathbf{x}$, conditioned upon these initial values, is then given by
> $$\overline{\mathbf{x}(t)} = \mathbf{G}(t) \mathbf{x}_0 \, . \tag{12.17}$$

So now it's reasonably clear why the noise is left out of $\mathbf{G}$.
Note that the noise does two things: 1) it determines the unconditioned probability distribution over $x_0$ and $v_0$, and 2) it leads to randomness in $x(t)$ and $v(t)$.
Therefore, for *given* values of $x_0$ and $v_0$ and taking the *average* of the conditional time dependent trajectories, the noise plays no role.
In other words, we're really just solving
$$\dot{\mathbf{x}} + \mathbf{\Gamma} \mathbf{x} = 0 $$
for which (12.17) is obviously the solution.
This is annoyingly poorly explained by the book, but at least it's discernibly correct.

Then the author writes

> The next step is to define the covariance matrix
> $$\mathbf{\sigma}(t) = 2 \int_0^t \mathbf{G}(t') \mathbf{D} \mathbf{G}^T (t') \, dt'$$
> where $\mathbf{G}^T$ denotes the transpose of the matrix $\mathbf{G}$.

I have no idea where this equation came from.
Why is this integral expression the correct one for the covariance?

Answer (score 1):

I apologize when I translate this into the stochastic differential equation background I am more familiar with. Relating white noise to a standard Wiener process $W_t$,
$$
W_t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m\gamma k_bT}}\int_0^t\eta(s)\,ds,
$$
we can write the Langevin equation as the system of one ODE and one SDE:
\begin{align}
dx_t&=(v_t-x_t)\,dt\\
dv_t&=-\gamma\,v_t\,dt-\frac{\sqrt{2m\gamma k_bT}}{m}\,dW_t\,.
\end{align}
Using $D=k_bT/\gamma m$ the SDE can be written as
$$
dv_t=-\gamma\,v_t\,dt-\gamma\sqrt{2D}\,dW_t\,.
$$
Using Ito's lemma we can verify that this SDE has the explicit solution
$$
v_t=e^{-\gamma t}\,v_0-\gamma\sqrt{2D}\,\,e^{-\gamma t}\int_0^te^{\gamma u}\,dW_u\,.
$$
The covariance function of the Gaussian process $v_t$ is
\begin{align}
{\rm Cov}[v_t,v_s]&=2\gamma^2D\,e^{-\gamma(t+s)}\int_0^{\min(t,s)}e^{2\gamma u}\,du=\gamma D\,e^{-\gamma(t+s)}\Big(e^{2\gamma\min(t,s)}-1\Big)\\
&=\gamma D\Big(e^{-\gamma|t-s|}-e^{-\gamma(t+s)}\Big)\,.
\end{align}
This is not exactly how the stationary $\sigma(t)$ seems to look like. The reason for this could be that there are two different definitions of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process.

- the stationary one does not follow a Langevin SDE
- the one that does is not stationary.

They are however closely related. See this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414621/a-gauss-markov-process-is-always-a-solution-to-a-langevin-type-sde/4414813#4414813).

Comment: Where does $dx_t = (v_t - x_t)dt$ come from?

Comment: The first component of the vector  $\dot{\mathbf{x}}+\mathbf{\Gamma}\mathbf{x}$ is zero according to the Langevin equation. Rewriting this with the components $x$ and $v$ of $\mathbf{x}$ gives $dx_t=(v_t-x_t)dt$.

Comment: Oh right, duh. Thank you.

Comment: I would like to understand how the treatment given in this answer relates to the integral $\sigma(t) = \int_0^t G(t') D G(t')^T \, dt'$ given in the question. Can you give me a hint? Near the end of the answer there is an expression for the covariance in terms of an integral... where does that come from?

Comment: I believe when you study the linked [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414621/a-gauss-markov-process-is-always-a-solution-to-a-langevin-type-sde/4414813#4414813) in detail you will understand more.  In short: there are TWO definitions of OU process, leading to different expressions for $\operatorname{Cov}[v_t,v_s]$, namely eq. (1) and (6) in the linked post. It might be redundant to translate all this into your notation.